# why my question got closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I asked a question yesterday and it got closed with 2 negative votes, I am not sure why it has been closed and how can I improve it,

https://serverfault.com/questions/510940/what-should-my-ip-address-be-for-my-dns-or-how-can-i-set-it-up

whereas there is a similar questions with +1 and +3 vote(s) and they are even not closed, there's just minor differences,

[How do you set up DNS in Window Server 2008 in a Hyper-V environment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2557/how-do-you-set-up-dns-in-window-server-2008-in-a-hyper-v-environment)

[What DNS records should I set up for a new server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/38238/what-dns-records-should-i-set-up-for-a-new-server?rq=1)

Comment: I see its gone now, but your first title of the question implied people didn't help you because of your name. I have never seen that kind of discrimination here. Ever. I don't know what kind of discrimination you experience in your own life but if you ever experience it here I will personally come down on them like a ton of bricks.

Comment: @Muhammad - your question is very amateurishly written, this site is for professionals. As for why the first question you refer to got an upvote I have no idea as it's almost as bad as yours, whereas the second one has almost nothing to do with what you appear to have 'asked' and DOES deserve the up-votes. Basically become a seasoned professional and ask appropriate questions in a professional way, until then just don't bother.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja: Server Fault moderators are all automatically notified of new questions on mSF which includes the title so we saw it in it's original form.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way; but I was actually standing up for you.

Answer (score 8):

Your question makes little sense, but mostly serves as evidence that you haven't done the least bit of self-education on the topic of setting up an Active Directory Domain. It's really not something you just stumble through, even when you're just learning. Get a book or find some good articles on topic. Read them. If you still have issues getting AD installed ask again.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your question was closed is given right after the announcement that it was closed:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, ...

You can see from the comments that your question was ambiguous.  Even after your update, it's hard to tell what you're doing.  And your question is certainly "overly broad" if you need instructions on everything from how to find the IP address of your laptop up to configuring the different networking options in whatever virtualization you're using (and that's what makes your question "incomplete" - you haven't provided enough details.)

Pointing to other questions that are 4 years old that (might, arguably) also be bad doesn't make your question any better.  Now that you've drawn attention to them, one of those questions also has a close vote...

Answer (score 2):

Muhammad, I'm sorry I wasn't more help.  I cast my close vote when I first saw the question, at which time I think it deserved it because it was, as I said, unanswerable in its original form.  As you improved it, it became clearer to me that it was specific to MS Windows, which I don't and won't use and know nothing about - so I had nothing further to add.

Other answers to this question tell me that those who do know about Windows feel that it's a very basic AD question, and I defer to their experience; that justifies closing it as off-topic for the site.

Addressing Mark Henderson's comment above, I'm sorry if you felt discriminated against, but at no time was my judgement based on anything besides the content of what you'd written.  I stand by my close vote given both the original state, and the current state, of your question, but I could have better communicated why I went silent.